# How to change the coloring of the mode shapes in Abaqus

Tags: abaqus

how can i change the coloring in Abaqus to be comparable with the ones I already got from matlab. your help will be really appreciated. 
[image: Abagus]
[image: Matlab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example of a custom color table for abaqus cae.  Save in a .py file and do "run script" while you are in contour plot module.

```
session.Spectrum(name="custom",colors=(\
'#000004','#010107','#02020C','#030312','#050417','#07051D','#0A0722',\
'#0D0828','#100A2E','#130B34','#170B3B','#1B0C41','#1F0C47','#230C4D',\
'#270B52','#2C0B57','#300A5C','#350A60','#390963','#3E0965','#420A68',\
'#460B69','#4A0C6B','#4E0D6C','#530E6D','#57106D','#5B116E','#5F136E',\
'#63146E','#67166E','#6B176E','#6F196E','#731A6E','#771C6D','#7B1D6D',\
'#7F1F6C','#83206B','#87216A','#8B2369','#8F2468','#932667','#982766',\
'#9C2964','#A02A63','#A42C61','#A82D5F','#AB2F5D','#AF315B','#B33359',\
'#B73557','#BB3755','#BF3952','#C23B50','#C63D4D','#C9404B','#CD4248',\
'#D04545','#D34842','#D74B3F','#DA4E3D','#DD513A','#DF5437','#E25734',\
'#E55B31','#E75F2D','#E9622A','#EC6627','#EE6A24','#F06E21','#F1721D',\
'#F3771A','#F57B17','#F67F13','#F78410','#F8880D','#F98D0A','#FA9207',\
'#FB9606','#FB9B06','#FCA007','#FCA50A','#FCA90E','#FCAE13','#FCB318',\
'#FBB81D','#FBBD23','#FAC229','#F9C72F','#F8CC36','#F7D13D','#F6D644',\
'#F5DB4C','#F4E055','#F3E55E','#F2E968','#F1EE72','#F2F27C','#F3F587',\
'#F5F991','#F8FC9B','#FCFFA4'))
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].odbDisplay.contourOptions.setValues(spectrum='custom')
```

I'll leave it to a matlab expert to figure how to get the hex codes for its contour color scheme.

Comment: Any idea if Abaqus requires the colors be spec'd in Hex?  Can I use RGB values?

Edit:  I just tried using `colors=([0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0])` and got an error that reads:  `TypeError:  colors[0], found tuple, expecting string`.